# Cant update a value in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I know there are a lot of questions that are like mine but still i cant get it to work?

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` and I'm not even enumerating I'm just trying to change the value of it but i get the error message:

> Mutating object sent to immutable object

here is the code..
I'm getting my dictionary as a parameter, lets call it `myDictionary`

```
NSString *stringToUpdate  = @"SomeString";
[myDictionary setObject:stringToUpdate forKey:@"time"];
```

this is where i get my Dictionary
**GameInfo.m**

```
     @class GameInfo;

@interface GetData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *gamesInfoArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict;


-(void) fetchData;
-(NSMutableArray *) getAllGames;
-(NSMutableArray *) getAllLiveGames;
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getGameInfoObject: (NSString *) gameObjectID;

-(void) postEventInfo: (NSDictionary *) eventInfoObject;

@end
```

**GameInfo.h**

```
  -(void) fetchData{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

    if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
        NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li", url, (long)[responseCode statusCode]);
    }

    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) getGameInfoObject: (NSString *) gameObjectID {

[self fetchData];

DataParser *dataParserObject = [[DataParser alloc] init];

return [dataParserObject sendBackDetailObject:jsonDict andGameID:gameObjectID]; 
// and this is where i send this NSMutableDictionary to the problem described on the top


}
```

Comment: The error is clear. Your `myDictionary` is an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: But im clearly marking it as NsMutableDictionary as the parameter and where i send it from is a NsMutableDictionary. lets say it is a NSDictionary how would i solve it then

Comment: The variable type is irrelevant. The actual object is not a mutable dictionary. Show the code where you actual set or obtain `myDictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:]` will return an immutable `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` by default.

You'll need to either take a copy of this and assign it to your instance variable

```
NSError *JSONError = nil;

jsonDict = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&JSONError] mutableCopy];

if (!jsonDict) {
  NSLog(@"Failed to parse JSON: %@", JSONError.localizedDescription);
}
```

Or provide the `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` option to JSON parsing method

```
NSError *JSONError = nil;

jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                             error:&JSONError];

if (!jsonDict) {
  NSLog(@"Failed to parse JSON: %@", JSONError.localizedDescription);
}
```